# Parse date together using 1 database field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to parse a date together for the previous fiscal year.  The fiscal year start month is stored in our database as FiscalYearStartMonth. 
This is what I had, but it doesn't work.

`CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(year,0,CONVERT(varchar,Year(GetDate())+ FiscalYearStartMonth + '01',106)))`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the start of your fiscal year in the current year

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', FiscalYearStartMonth, '-01');
```

If you want to find the date in the past, I'm afraid my answer is a bit complicated. I'm sure there is a better solution:

```
SELECT date 
FROM ( 
   SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', FiscalYearStartMonth, '-01') AS date 
   UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()) - 1, '-', FiscalYearStartMonth, '-01')
) AS dates 
WHERE date < NOW() 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```